# String statement returning null from switch statement

Tags: java, android, string, null, switch-statement

I am currently working on an Android application that allows you to watch streaming video in a VideoView. I have a method for allowing you to select one of four streams via a switch statement. That is working correctly and the code for that is as follows:

```
public void playStream(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            streamOn = true;
            streamPos = 0;
            logString = "M";
            posSelected = "0";
            break;
        case 1:
            streamOn = true;
            streamPos = 1;
            logString = "J";
            posSelected = "1";
            break;
        case 2:
            streamOn = true;
            streamPos = 2;
            logString = "B";
            posSelected = "2";
            break;
        case 3:
            streamOn = true;
            streamPos = 3;
            logString = "N";
            posSelected = "3";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    checkStreamLink(position);

    Log.wtf(logString, posSelected);
    Log.wtf(logString, streamURL);
}
```

What is not working correctly is that in this method for selecting the stream, I have a call to another method ( `checkStreamLink();` ) that runs a thread. Depending on which stream you have selected, the thread will call another method that opens up a webpage, reads a line of text, and then sets that text to a `String streamURL`. The code for those two methods is as follows:

```
public void checkStreamLink(final int position) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        streamURL = getStreamLink("LINK 0 GOES HERE");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        streamURL = getStreamLink("LINK 1 GOES HERE");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        streamURL = getStreamLink("LINK 2 GOES HERE");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        streamURL = getStreamLink("LINK 3 GOES HERE");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}


public String getStreamLink (String textSource) {
    URL streamURL;
    String errorParsingURL = "ERROR PARSING URL";
    try {
        streamURL = new URL(textSource);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(streamURL.openStream()));
        String StringBuffer;
        String stringText = "";
        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringText += StringBuffer;
        }
        bufferReader.close();
        return stringText;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return errorParsingURL;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the `String streamURL` is returning null on its first use as evidenced by the `Log` statements I have included. Each time you select a stream after that, the `String streamURL` returns the text that you should have received the previous time you select a stream. I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening and I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: what is the value of position variable? does it also lag?

Comment: ...do you somehow wait for this thread to finish? because if not there's a very good chance that your logging code runs before the thread.

Comment: @RJadhav, the position variable is just the position in the array for where all the stream names are. It does not lag at all.

Comment: @radai, I was under the assumption that the thread finished and the code was logged, but playing around with additional log statements is showing me otherwise now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a null because **getStreamLink** is returning its value after you have already printed the result. Print the result log messages at the end of the **getStreamLink** method to see the actual value which is being returned, and call any additional functionality at that point as well.

Comment: Thank you, Justin Reda. This put me in the right direction. You are a great help.